# My PS4 streams aren't being archived

Tags: ps4, streaming

I had done two previous streams with my PS4 for Killzone and NFS rivals and they were archived. However, my most recent stream of NFS Rivals (3 days ago) did not. Archiving is set as enabled in my Twitch account, so I'm confused why my previous stream isn't existing anywhere, even for editing.

Is there a setting on my PS4 that could be the culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitch archiving is not suppose to be working yet. This feature is not yet implemented but planned([Eurogamer](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2013-11-22-twitch-planning-to-add-livestream-archives-on-ps4)). Though several users report that some streams seems to be archived.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, then. I was worried there was something broken somewhere.